# How to get the final URL after an Ajax redirect?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on an AJAX script that makes a GET request to a shortened URL, like a bit.ly link. How do I actually get the URL of the final/redirected page?

I can get the response headers from the redirected page, but it doesn't appear to contain the URL information:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.thislinkredirects.com",
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    var response = $(data);
  },
  complete: function(xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
  }
});
```

Result:

```
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2015 03:22:07 GMT
Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Server: lighttpd/1.4.35
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Content-type: text/html
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, authorization
```

I do not have control of the server making the get request.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was making an AJAX call to this site http://www.wheregoes.com/retracer.php and artificially submitting the form on there to get the final location of the URL. It's a huge workaround but it works.

Answer (score 19):

As I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48445360/1398908

A better solution is to supply jQuery's ajax with a custom xhr object like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

$.ajax({
    url: '/url',
    type: 'post',
    data: '...',
    xhr: function() {
         return xhr;
    }
});
```

Then you can access the current URL in any callback

```
success: function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseURL);
}
```

**Note: IE doesn't support the responseURL property.** (See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL))

Comment: This is one of the nicest solutions out there. However, one should know that IE doesn't support the responseURL property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL

Comment: @papazulu this is SO important to advice at. Almost anybody develops for IE, but sadly there is plenty of users browsing the internet with it. Thanks

Comment: How can you access the responseUrl or location header from the activex object for IE?

Comment: @daptordarattler Asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976614/xmlhttprequest-responseurl-in-ie), too. It seems there was no way in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `jqXHR` to ajaxComplete and then read the header.

The header should show a `Location:` field.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing but so far the majority of the redirecting links that I'm testing do not have the Location field.

Comment: See if you are able to get the location by trying to extract only that using: `xhr.getResponseHeader('Location')`

Comment: Doing that returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily i had a canonical tag:

```js
var matches = xhr.responseText.match(/<link rel="canonical" href="([^"]+)"\/>/);
var url = matches[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.....

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=e40f15a90**c89851d8a66&redirect_uri=http://examle.com&response_type=token",
  success:function(result,status,xhr){
    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));<---NULL
  }
});
```