# XMLHttpRequest.responseURL in IE

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking a way to get [`XMLHttpRequest.responseURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL) in IE.

My code (`myreq.responseURL`) works correctly using Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

Is there a way to do the same (also using another function) in IE?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: [Discussion](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/443#issuecomment-342862921) of the fetch polyfil creators back then. Seems just not implemented :-/

Answer (score 3):

`XMLHttpRequest.responseURL` is not supported in IE as of yet.

The closest alternative I could think of is `XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader()`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the response, you can use `response.config`. So in my case, this worked:

```
const originalUrl = response.request.responseURL || response.config.url
```