# How to get a redirect URL with Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Right now, I am using JQuery for:

```
$.get(url, function() {
  ...
});
```

`url` is an external website that then redirects. Is there any way to get the final redirect URL using Javascript or JQuery?

Additionally, I have tried examining the response headers but there is no 'Location' header returned.

Comment: Does the request succeed? Suspect you run into CORS problems as a result of  that redirect

Comment: @charlietfl The request does succeed and returns the data it needs to. I just can't find a way to get that final redirect url :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the final URL after an Ajax redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993442/how-to-get-the-final-url-after-an-ajax-redirect)

Comment: How do you know it gets redirected in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl If I use the browser to navigate to that URL, it is redirected to another page.

Comment: Do you mean to redirect to a new page like this  window.location = "/signin" ?